# Chrome Extension: Injected button's onclick not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Working with chrome extension for the first time. Right now I have a button and a modal injected to a page from the content script.

Adding the button

```
var button1 = document.createElement("button");
button1.innerHTML = "Button";
button1.onclick = openModal;
document.querySelector('.myClass').appendChild(button1);
```

Adding the modal

```
var modal = document.createElement("div");
modal.classList.add('modal');
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Close";
button.onclick = closeModal;
modal.appendChild(button);
document.body.appendChild(modal);
```

I define the the styles in the class modal where I set the display as 'none'

inside openModal

```
function openModal(){
    var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

to display the modal.

and inside closeModal

```
function closeModal(){
    var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

to close the modal.

This is a generalized format of what I'm creating. The first button's onclick works fine and opens the modal but the second button to close the modal doesn't work. Any clue as to what is wrong here?

Comment: Can you try changing none to "none"

Comment: @TusharShahi it is "none" sorry forgot to add that in the code. The closeModal isn't firing at all on the second button click. I added an alert statement for test and no result

Comment: Also, i hope the 2 variables called buttons are in different scope? Since they have the same names. How are you accessing modal inside the remove and add function. Can you add those in the question description?

Comment: Is your add modal a separate function? When is it called?

Answer (score 0):

Ok not sure what happened here but I added some additional codes that injected new js codes that took the window click event and compare the event to the class of the modal to close it. After making these changes somehow the closeModal function started to fire as well. Not exactly sure if it was a caching error or something but it works now. So if anyone is having similar issues maybe trying clearing cache and trying again.